# Search for multiple question marks in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to search for multiple signs in my dataset with pandas. For example when I search for multiple explanation points I use this script that works:

```
df_double=df[df["text"].str.contains("!!")==True]
df_double
```

But when I want to change this script to search for multiple question marks, I get an error:

```
df_double=df[df["text"].str.contains("??")==True]
df_double
```

What is wrong with this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\` for escape `?`, because special regex chars with `{2}` for specify `2 chars`:

```
df1 = df[df["text"].str.contains("\?{2}", na=False)]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df["text"].str.contains("\?\?", na=False)]
```